# how to exclude Aspectj in SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I m a newbie to spring boot tests.Here is my situation:
  I want to run spring boot test but exclude some components like component contains @Aspect annotation.Because in my test case, some code will be cut in by aspect component and cause NullPointException.

---

*I tried to use @SpringBootTest parameter classes like this
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestApplication.class) ,and TestApplication.class is a springboot Main class with @ComponentScan annotation for scan components exclude @Aspect class.I think it is not a clear way to solve this problem and it does not work for me*, can anybody help me?

---

1.Test Case: please look at comment flag 1. that is a query database operation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CheckCardFormatTest{
   @Autowired
   private XxxServiceImpl xxxService; // service layer 
   ....
   @Test
    public void testMainCardFormat() {
        String result=xxxService.query("someParam");// 1.
         ....
    }
   ....
}
```

2.here is the problem please look at comment 2, getRequest() method will cause NullPointException.Because my aspect class will interrupt query-database operation

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AbcAspect {
  @Around(value = "execution(*com.xx.preparedStatement_execute(..))")
  public Object druidIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
  ....
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes;
    HttpServletRequest request = servletRequestAttributes.getRequest();// 2.
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add @TestComponent to AbcsAspect class 
here is the javadoc of @TestComponent

> /**
>    * {@link Component @Component} that can be used when a bean is intended only for tests,
>    * and should be excluded from Spring Boot's component scanning.
>    *
>
> * Note that if you directly use {@link ComponentScan @ComponentScan} rather than relying
>    * on {@code @SpringBootApplication} you should ensure that a {@link TypeExcludeFilter} is
>    * declared as an {@link ComponentScan#excludeFilters() excludeFilter}.
>    *
>    * @author Phillip Webb
>    * @since 1.4.0
>    * @see TypeExcludeFilter
>    * @see TestConfiguration
>    */